# Proving that certain subset of the Grassmannian is open in the Zariski topology.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{G}(k,n)$ be the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$, and let $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{n}$ be an irreducible algebraic variety.
Fix a positive integer $m$. We define
$$
r=\mathrm{max}\{\mathrm{dim}\langle p_{1},\ldots,p_{m}\rangle:p_{1},\ldots,p_{m}\in X\}.
$$
I want to prove that
$$
S=\{\langle p_{1},\ldots,p_{m}\rangle:p_{1},\ldots,p_{m}\in X, \mathrm{dim}\langle p_{1},\ldots,p_{m}\rangle=r\}\subseteq\mathbb{G}(r,n)
$$
is an open subset of the Grassmannian $\mathbb{G}(r,n)$.

I have tried to find equations for $\mathbb{G}(r,n)-S$ taking into account that  $\mathbb{G}(r,n)$ is identified with an algebraic variety  via de Plücker embedding, but I have not been able. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a quantification problem in your question: the way you state it, $r$ depends on $m$ and then your definition of $S$ does not make sense because $m$ is not quantified. You might want to make $m$ a variable in the definition of $r$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg thanks for the clarification. I have edited the question,  Is it correct now?

Comment: No. Do you want $r$ to be the largest dimension of the linear subspaces of $\mathbb P^n$ generated by a finite number  of number of points of $X$?  I have taken the liberty of modifying your question in that interpretation. If you don't like my modification you can roll back to your present version and I will leave it at that.

Comment: Dear Gauloises, all right, I'll leave your question as is. Can you please explain what happens when $X\subset \mathbb P^2$ is a line:  what  is $r$ and what is the resulting open subset of $\mathbb G(r,2)$ ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg If $m>1$ then $r=1$ and $S$ is the original line as an element of $\mathbb{G}(1,n)$. If $m=1$, then $r=0$ and $S$ is the set of points in the original line as elements of $\mathbb{G}(0,n)=\mathbb{P}^{n}$. According to this, maybe we should impose certain conditions on the numbers for the result to be true, but I would like to prove the result for a fixed $m$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg In fact, I think your comment solves the problem, because it shows that the result is not true.

Comment: I have now  made my comments more explicit  in an  answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersction of all linear subspaces  $W\subset \mathbb P^n$ containing $X$ ( i.e. $W\supset X$) is a linear  subspace $V\subset \mathbb P^n$, whose dimension we call $r$.
For any integer $m$ and any choice of points $p_1,\cdots,p_m\in X$ we have $$\langle p,\cdots,p_m \rangle \subset V \quad (\bigstar)$$ and for at least one integer $M$ and one choice of points $q_1,\cdots,q_M\in X$ we have $$\langle q_1,\cdots,q_M \rangle = V \quad (\bigstar \bigstar)$$ There is only one linear subspace of $\mathbb P^n$  satisfying both $(\bigstar)$   and  $(\bigstar \bigstar)$ : that subspace is $V$ .
The corresponding point              $ [V]\in\mathbb G(r, \mathbb P^n)$ is a closed point of  $\mathbb G(r, \mathbb P^n)$ and   certainly not an open subset of that grassmannian.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\dim\left<p_1,\dots,p_r\right>$ is the same as the rank of the matrix whose rows are $p_1,\dots,p_m$.  Now use the fact that a matrix has rank $<s$ if and only if all $s\times s$ minors vanish.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please explain what happens when $X\subset \mathbb P^2$ is a line: what are $r$ and the resulting open subset of $\mathbb G(r,2)$ ?

Comment: $r=1$ and $S$ is the set of all points in $\mathbb G(1, 2)=\mathbb P^2$ is the whole of $X$.

Comment: How is that an open subset of  $\mathbb G(1,2)=(\mathbb P^2)^ \star \:$?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg It's not; my guess is that the OP meant that $S$ should be an open subset of the subvariety of $\mathbb G(r, n)$ corresponding to $X$.

Comment: You are right, I agree.